# Workaround for external API which does not have CORS enabled?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cors, docusignapi

What can be the workarounds for using an external API like Docusign which does not have CORS enabled and requires a custom HTTP header for authentication ?

I am trying to integrate this API with my angular app running on localhost.

I cannot add Access-Control-Allow-Origin Header and disabling web security on Chrome is a foolish solution.

JSONP is also out of the window as I cannot add a custom HTTP Header to a JSONP request.

Comment: Please make the question more clear, try describing a complete situation with source code example and the expected behavior.

Answer (score 2):

> What can be the workarounds for using an external API like Docusign which does not have CORS enabled and requires a custom HTTP header for authentication ?

I dont know Docusign but if they dont support CORS nor jsonp, You just cant send an ajax request from AngularJS.You need a proxy server app that will do the call.