# How to programmatically access DocuSign History and Certificate of Completion

Tags: docusignapi

I am using an embedded view. When the user clicks finish I would like to be able to programmatically grab the History and Certificate of Completion so we can store the documents in our system.

Is there anyway of achieving this?

Answer (score 5):

#### Envelope History

Use the [listAuditEvents](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopes/listauditevents/) api to get the envelope history.

```
GET /v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/audit_events
```

---

#### Certificate of Completion

Use the [getEnvelopeDocuments](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopedocuments/get/) api to download the certificate of completion.
Pass `certificate` as the **documentId**.

```
GET /v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/documents/certificate
```

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43793686/1219543) for the c# code

Comment: Won't this cause cross-domain issues if I'm making this call from my local machine?

Comment: Only if you are calling from a browser using javascript. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25167540/1219543).  If you are calling from a server side program like (Java or .Net) then there should not be any issues.